# Link to a list item from a document library

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, document-library, modern-experience, folder

I have a SharePoint list "A" which each record has a unique number called "enq no"., when the list record is created it also creates folders in a document library.  This document library record has subfolders.  I need to create a link in these subfolders back to the list record.

Both the list and subfolders in the library has the unique number "enq no.", but I need the list ID to be able to create a url back to the list item.

How do I get the list ID so I can use it in a link?

Novice to all of this.

Comment: Hi @Sandra, did you try below suggestions? is it working for you?

Answer (score 0):

Follow this steps:

1. Navigate to the SharePoint list using the browser.
2. Select the **Settings** (gear icon at the top right corner >> **List Settings**
3. You can find the List GUID in URL

Example URL:

```
http://moss2007/ProjectX/_layouts/listedit.aspx?List=%7B26534EF9%2DAB3A%2D46E0%2DAE56%2DEFF168BE562F%7D
```

Decode this URL using any tool online and you will left with the list ID like:

```
{26534EF9-AB3A-46E0-AE56-EFF168BE562F}
```

**Reference**: [Finding the Id (Guid) for a SharePoint List](https://nickgrattan.wordpress.com/2008/04/29/finding-the-id-guid-for-a-sharepoint-list/)

Comment: There are other programmatic options available too like using PowerShell or SharePoint REST APIs.